# SharePoint subsite has unique permissions from parent site but all users able to access the subsite

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, custom-permission-level

We have one main site in SharePoint 2013 and so many subsites. Few subsite has unique permissions from parent site. But all users are able to access the those unique subsite. They are able view content and access it.

For testing purpose, i had removed all users and groups from subsite. Then tried to access from one test user. If there is no permission for any user means test user need to get access denied message. But test user able to access the subsite and content also accessing.

When i checked permissions for user its showing below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only things that come up to mind right now:

1. Anonymous access is enabled at this site level
2. Or these users have been added at the *Web application* level (from CA), via a group.

Answer (score 0):

When you see all of the individual permissions listed like that, then the user is a Site Collection Administrator or has been granted "super user" permissions (User Policy) in Central Administration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by going to Central Administration, Application Management, Manage Web Applications, Click on main application, User Policy.  I had Everyone set to MySite Subsite Creation.  I removed that and everything worked as it should!

[image]